# Can a C struct behave like it had a function?

Tags: object-oriented, c, data-structures

I use C and `struct`s where a struct can have members but not functions. Assume for simplicity that I want to create a struct for strings that I name `str` and I want to be able to do `str.replace(int i, char c)` where `i` is the index of the string and `c` is the character to replace the character at position `i`. Would this never be possible since structs can't have functions or is there still some way we can implement this behavior and mimic that a struct could have a (simple) function that actually only is the struct copying itself to a new struct and updating its fields, which it could do?

So `replace` could be a third member of the struct that points to a new struct that is updated when it is accessed or similar. Could it be done? Or is there something builtin or some theory or paradigm that prevents my intention?

The background is that I'm writing C code and I find myself reinventing functions that I know are library builtins in OOP languages and that OOP would be a good way to manipulate strings and commands.

Comment: I honestly think you would be better off writing free functions to do this sort of thing.  However, if you have the necessary moxie, read https://www.cs.rit.edu/~ats/books/ooc.pdf

Comment: Structs can include variables which are pointers to functions. No built in inheritance but you can instantiate your struct with the pointers pointing to different functions with the same signature. You'll often want to make the first parameter to the function a pointer to the struct.

Comment: is replace(&str, i, c) *really* that much worse than str.replace(i,c)? Your question isn't actually about replacing functions, it's about trying to smush a new syntax into C.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Thanks for the  https://www.cs.rit.edu/~ats/books/ooc.pdf  link. Nice book (and the price is right).

Comment: @RobertHarvey If you are associated with the linked book, there is a spelling mistake in the second sentence on the very first page. This is why spell-check should not be relied upon. - Your friendly neighbourhood spelling nazi.

Comment: @whatsisname: In C, you have to pass the structure pointer to the function anyway, so you end up with `str.replace(&str, i, c)` anyway.  C++ automates the passing of the `this` pointer, of course.

Comment: Manipulating strings isn't related to OOP. And the dot syntax on non-virtual methods is just syntactic sugar. So there is nothing useful that you'll get out of this.

Comment: @Toby: I have nothing to do with the linked book.  I'm just fascinated with programming languages and how you can stretch them, and I knew about the book already.

Comment: Don't try to shoehorn OO techniques into an imperative language. C already has so many warts, trying to add do things it wasn't designed for will only cause more headaches.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Your function should look like this.

```
void
replace(struct string * s, int i, char c);
```

This accepts a pointer to the object to operate on as the first parameter. In C++, this is known as the `this`-pointer and need not be declared explicitly. (Contrast this to Python where it has to.)

In order to call your function, you would also pass that pointer explicitly. Basically, you trade the `o.f(…)` syntax for the `f(&o, …)` syntax. Not a big deal.

The story becomes more involved if you want to support *polymorphism* (aka `virtual` functions). It can also be emulated in C (I've shown it for [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33007415/1392132).) but it ain't pretty to do by hand.

As [Jan Hudec](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/38200/jan-hudec) has commented, you should also make it a habit to prefix the function name with the type name (ie `string_replace`) because C has no name-spaces so there can only be a single function named `replace`.

Comment: Of course the function will probably have to be called `string_replace`, because C does not have function overloading either and you are likely to have some other `replace` for some other type…

Comment: It can't be named `string_replace`. Names beginning with `str`, `mem`, or `wcs` followed by a lowercase letter are reserved for future extensions.

Answer (score 43):

Structs can hold function *pointers*, but those are really only needed for virtual methods.  Non-virtual methods in object-oriented C are usually done by passing the struct as the first argument to a regular function.  Look at  [Gobject](https://developer.gnome.org/gobject/) for a good example of an OOP framework for C.  It uses macros to handle a lot of the boilerplate required for inheritance and polymorphism.

C was created 44 years ago.  It's a very popular language for open source.  You're not the first person to think standard C strings are clunky to work with.  Do some searches for C string libraries.  You don't have to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Other notable example is CPython. The code uses a lot of OOP concepts yet it's 100% pure C.

Comment: @Bakuriu I think you're confusing [Cython](http://cython.org/) and [CPython](http://python.org)

Comment: @cat He probably means the Python C API, Cython isn't 100% pure C. https://docs.python.org/c-api/intro.html

Comment: @cat No. Look at CPython sources. Most of the things are indeed done using the OOP paradigm, and they provide an OOP API that mostly matches the python API.

Comment: @Bakuriu Oh, you mean Python's runtime, source and C API not the Python language. your comment didn't make that very clear

Answer (score 8):

With function pointers, you can do:

```
str.replace(&str, i, c);
```

This is generally only useful if the implementation can change, in which case you should use a vtable so the overhead is only one pointer per struct:

```
str.vtable->replace(&str, i, c);
```

Comment: I'd tend to still call it as string_replace(&str, i, c) then use the vtable inside string_replace rather than have the call site know about the vtable.

Comment: @Pete Names beginning with `str` (or `mem` or `wcs`) and a lowercase letter are reserved by the C standard for future extensions, so don't call it `string_replace`. `str_replace` is fine.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, they can, sort of. You can make use of the fact that C allows for pointers to function blocks in memory, a.k.a. function pointers and using that you may create interface like polymorphism as well as virtual functions (even if it is not that pretty).

I wrote a blog post on this subject, following a question from one of my students, recently, pertaining to interface-like code in C and Go, you can read it here:

[Blog post on non-OO interfaces](http://www.tyregrim.se/c/a-non-oo-interface-system/)

See if it gives you any ideas.

You could also just put a free function in your code, and use a "this"-pointer, meaning you pass a pointer to an existing struct to work on, as described in other answers.